# Bootstrap isn't responding

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I created a WP theme template that already has Bootstrap "installed" and ready to go. I use this for most of my projects and have never had a problem.

For some reason, this particular website isn't responding when I resize the browser screen.

View here: http://staging.ceobusinessalliance.com/about/

I'm trying to troubleshoot the issue but I can't find anything wrong. Here is the basics of the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting Bootstrap CSS with this line of code in your style.css file, which gives your website a fixed width of 1080px.

```
.container { width: 1080px !important; padding: 0; }
```

You need to remove `width: 1080px !important;`

Comment: Oh man. I knew it was something simple. Thanks so much, Charles!

Comment: Thanks. Please consider accepting my response as the correct answer if it solved your problem. ;)